# Array index equivalent with a pointer

Tags: c

If I have:

```
char    str2[]  = "Word2";
```

What is the equivalent of doing:

```
str2[1] = 'a';
```

My thought was the following but it seems like this is pretty overkill:

```
(
 // part 3 -- cast memory address (int) as pointer
 * (char *)
 // part 1 -- get the memory address as an int
 ((long)&str2
 // part 2 -- get the index of 1 by +1 memory address
 +1)
) = 'a';
```

Comment: `str2[1]` is equivalent to `*(str2 + 1)`.

Comment: @dxiv is `str2` an int type then or does the `+ 1` operation cast it to a number?

Comment: `str2` decays to a `char*` and `+1` is the usual pointer arithmetic. There is no need for, and in fact no place for, involving integer types in this.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 When a pointer is incremented, it actually increments by the number equal to the size of the data type for which it is a pointer, so there is no casting.

Comment: `What is the equivalent`,,there can be many equivalents, question is what syntax you're interested in?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
char str2[] = "word2";
```

sets the name `str2` as an array type to the first byte of consecutive memory locations storing the string `"word2"`, particularly `str2` will point to a byte in memory storing the character `w`. (However note that, `str2` is not a pointer, see the comments below.)

Note that if you now try to dereference `str2 + 1`, which follows pointer arithmetic, the pointer will be incremented by the size of the data type of the element being pointed at, which here is of `char` type and hence address pointed by `str2 + 1` will be precisely 1 byte (size of `char` data type) away from the address pointed by `str`. Thus, `str2 + 1` will point to the memory byte having 'o'.

Your seemingly overkill code

> (  // part 3 -- cast memory address (int) as pointer  * (char *)  //
> part 1 -- get the memory address as an int  ((long)&str2  // part 2 --
> get the index of 1 by +1 memory address  +1) ) = 'a';

works because is `char` is of size 1 byte and hence the `+1` part takes the pointer to the next byte which is also the next character in the string. Had it been an integer array, you would have to increment by 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the size of `int` in your system) to get to the next element of the array.

The equivalent code segments for whatever you are trying to achieve are already in the comments by `dxiv`. I just wanted to clarify things a bit.

Comment: Re “sets the name `str2` as a constant pointer”: An array is not a pointer. In many expressions, an array is automatically converted to a pointer. But not all. When a student is taught this false idea, they have to unlearn it later and learn the correct rules.

Comment: That is precisely why I mentioned the term constant pointer. You cannot assign anything else to the right hand side of an array name. But you could if it were a pointer i.e., declared by char *str (instead of char str[] here).

Comment: I am sorry I might be missing something but I am sure I have seen in literature that the array name is a constant pointer to the first element of the array. May be I am used to think it this way because they are so functionally identical. Thank you for pointing this out, I will look it up.

Comment: `sizeof x` is generally different for an array and a pointer. `&x` is different for an array and a pointer. If an array were a pointer (constant or otherwise), the array `x` of `int x[3][4]` could be passed as an argument for a parameter of type `int **` (or `int * const * const`). It cannot, as they are incompatible types. Stack Overflow repeatedly sees questions raised by these mistaken concepts. Do not teach the wrong idea.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for clarifying this. I guess I was under the illusion of the wrong idea too! I will try to be more aware regarding these things in the future.